# Javascript automatic close down popup window after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to make a javascript popup whit an advertisement, and then close down after 10 seconds, i have searched the internet for anything to do that, but i can't find anything.

I am not a very expirenced javascript programmer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function() {  


        var id = '#dialog';


        //Get the screen height and width

        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect     
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     


});

</script>
```

Best regards,

Jeppe S

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Comment: @JeppeS : Please take a moment to read : http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and http://sscce.org/

Comment: Your code uses JQuery. Be sure to include required files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(id).hide();
}, 10000);
```